# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. Could not fin

Tags: flutter

I changed my flutter version from 3.0.5 to 2.8.0 so i can continue developing for an old project.
Now i am facing this error :
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13.
> I had many errors with my Java and gradel but i solved them and my error messages is as following.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :barcode_scan

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException()("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.wincom.erp.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and my gradel file is as following :

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thank you inh advance

tried changing compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31 and the targeted sdk too